# Android Studio Bumblebee Doesnt Build with Java 1.8

Tags: android, android-studio

After upgrading to Bumblebee, it cant build my projects anymore.

Keeps saying about java 1.8. does it require java 11?

Answer (score 0):

JDK 11 is a requirement since Artic Fox, there's no way around that

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#jdk-11

Comment: i was using arctic fox and my project is still using 1.8. but my gradle 4.2.2 not 7. guess there is no way around this then with bumblebee

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that it is very much recommended to align gradle plugin version with the Android Studio. And using JDK 11 is really not that much of a problem, there aren't that many changes there

Answer (score 0):

You neeed to use JDK 11 for building your project. First download it from android studio itself and then Invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: yeah. it's ok. i switched all my projects to java 11. no choice.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your JDK version. At least your JDK version must be 11 Then restart Android studio Check this link for more information: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#jdk-11

[image]

Comment: thanks. ive been using it then. works ok